# F1 renewal with 10 months to expire

Tags: visa-renewals

My F1 visa expires Aug 2024 but my OPT is valid until June 2025. So, I am planning to get my visa renewed when I visit home in Nov 2023.

Is it too early for a renewal appointment, considering I have 10 months until my visa expires?

Comment: Why do you need another visa besides your current visa? Do you have a need to leave and re-enter the US between Aug 2024 and June 2025 for some reason?